# What is the exact algorithm of `git --shallow-since`?

Tags: git, shallow-clone

If I call

```
git clone --shallow-since 2019-09-20 https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs.git
```

I cannot access commit 56985dd8a6, although it is from 2019-09-21.  Git stops at the red line in the following screenshot:

[image: Screnshot of gitk]

I don’t understand the algorithm here.  While the next commit is of 2019-09-17, so one could assume that it stops when it hits the first too old commit, there was already one of 2019-07-10 before that.  So, what are the rules of `--shallow-since`?

Comment: I don't think it's specified anywhere. Grab a clone of the Git repository for Git and find it in the source.

Comment: This always works, yes. But possibly someone has already done that and shares their knowledge. FWIW, I don’t read C.